# Question about Horses

Tags: recreational-mathematics

For P(n) being the assertion that in every set of n horses, all horses have the same color: P (n) ⇒ P (n + 1), when n > 1.

How do I prove this problem, can someone give me explanation or a headstart?

Comment: This is a frequently cited example of why one must be careful with induction. See, e.g. [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_horses_are_the_same_color).

Comment: I just don't get it, for example if 2 horses have the same color, then how did math proves that the third one is also the same color?

Comment: @T.Bongers: In fact $P(n)$ **does** imply $P(n+1)$ when $n>1$. The problem is getting from $n=1$ to $n=2$.